# Conflict between double column teaser image and institute info Latex

Tags: floats, pdftex, titles

I'm trying to add a top teaser image to cover two columns of a scientific double column article in latex but there is a conflict between such an image and institute information. When I add the image, it makes institute information disappear. The problem occurs on the svjour3.cls template.

Here is my code for the teaser image:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}

\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}        

\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{cite}

\usepackage{times}
%\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{multirow,stackengine}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}


\newcolumntype{$}{>{\global\let\currentrowstyle\relax}}
\newcolumntype{^}{>{\currentrowstyle}}
\newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}%
    #1\ignorespaces
}

\usepackage{pifont}

\usepackage[pagebackref=true,breaklinks=true,letterpaper=true,colorlinks,bookmarks=false]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\title{Insert your title here}
\subtitle{Do you have a subtitle?\\ If so, write it here}

\author{First Author         \and
        Second Author %etc.
}

\institute{F. Author \at
              first address \\
              Tel.: +123-45-678910\\
              Fax: +123-45-678910\\
              \email{fauthor@example.com}           %  \\
%             \emph{Present address:} of F. Author  %  if needed
           \and
           S. Author \at
              second address
}

\date{Received: date / Accepted: date}

% TEASER IMAGE -------------------------------------------------------
\twocolumn[{%
    \renewcommand\twocolumn[1][]{#1}%
    \maketitle
    \begin{center}
        \centering
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}
        \begin{tabular}{c c c}  
            
            \includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example.eps}
            \includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example.eps}
            \includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example.eps} \\
                
    \end{tabular}
            \captionof{figure}{\textbf{Caption of your teaser figure.} Please insert the caption of your teaser figure here.
            }
            \label{fig:teaser}
        \end{center}
        \vspace{0.5cm}
}]
% TEASER IMAGE -------------------------------------------------------

%\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Insert your abstract here. Include keywords, PACS and mathematical
subject classification numbers as needed.
\keywords{First keyword \and Second keyword \and More}
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
\label{intro}
Your text comes here. Separate text sections with
\section{Section title}
\label{sec:1} 
Text with citations \cite{RefB} and \cite{RefJ}.
\subsection{Subsection title}
\label{sec:2}
as required. Don't forget to give each section
and subsection a unique label (see Sect.~\ref{sec:1}).
\paragraph{Paragraph headings} Use paragraph headings as needed.
\begin{equation}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation}

% For one-column wide figures use
\begin{figure}
% Use the relevant command to insert your figure file.
% For example, with the graphicx package use
  \includegraphics{example.eps}
% figure caption is below the figure
\caption{Please write your figure caption here}
\label{fig:1}       % Give a unique label
\end{figure}
%
% For two-column wide figures use
\begin{figure*}
% Use the relevant command to insert your figure file.
% For example, with the graphicx package use
  \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{example.eps}
% figure caption is below the figure
\caption{Please write your figure caption here}
\label{fig:2}       % Give a unique label
\end{figure*}
%
% For tables use
\begin{table}
% table caption is above the table
\caption{Please write your table caption here}
\label{tab:1}       % Give a unique label
% For LaTeX tables use
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
first & second & third  \\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
number & number & number \\
number & number & number \\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


% Non-BibTeX users please use
\begin{thebibliography}{}
%
% and use \bibitem to create references. Consult the Instructions
% for authors for reference list style.
%
\bibitem{RefJ}
% Format for Journal Reference
Author, Article title, Journal, Volume, page numbers (year)
% Format for books
\bibitem{RefB}
Author, Book title, page numbers. Publisher, place (year)
% etc
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
% end of file template.tex
```

Calling the maketitle inside the image makes the institute information disappear. On attached image, left figure corresponds with version with teaser image, right figure is the output by only replacing all the teaser figure code by `maketitle`.

Is there a workaround to fix this and have both the teaser figure and institute information? I've tried several things without success. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) please extend your example to a complete minimal example that others can test as is. We have no idea what document class this is suppose to be using.

Comment: (1) Thanks for your response and nice welcome. (2) I posted the complete document now, it is the template from the svjour3.cls class. Downloaded from https://www.springer.com/gp/livingreviews/latex-templates (LaTeX Macro Package (zip, 182 kB) [all journals]). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\maketitle` (and `\@maketitle`) for svjour3 is VERY complicated.  It uses `\if@twocolumn` to make many formatting changes. The good news is that you don't have to redefine `\twocolumn`.  The bad news is that the title is formatted for a one column version of svjourn.

Institute is printed as a footnote, so must be added outside the `\twocolumn` argument (group).

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}

\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}        

\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{cite}

\usepackage{times}
%\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{multirow,stackengine}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}


\newcolumntype{$}{>{\global\let\currentrowstyle\relax}}
\newcolumntype{^}{>{\currentrowstyle}}
\newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}%
    #1\ignorespaces
}

\usepackage{pifont}

\usepackage[pagebackref=true,breaklinks=true,letterpaper=true,colorlinks,bookmarks=false]{hyperref}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\begin{document}

\title{Insert your title here}
\subtitle{Do you have a subtitle?\\ If so, write it here}

\author{First Author         \and
        Second Author %etc.
}

\institute{F. Author \at
              first address \\
              Tel.: +123-45-678910\\
              Fax: +123-45-678910\\
              \email{fauthor@example.com}           %  \\
%             \emph{Present address:} of F. Author  %  if needed
           \and
           S. Author \at
              second address
}

\date{Received: date / Accepted: date}

% TEASER IMAGE -------------------------------------------------------
\savebox{\tempbox}{\begin{tabular}{c c c}% no idea why this is needed
            \includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example.eps} &
            \includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example.eps} &
            \includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example.eps}
        \end{tabular}}
\twocolumn[
    \maketitle
    \begin{center}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}%
        \usebox\tempbox
        \captionof{figure}{\textbf{Caption of your teaser figure.} Please insert the caption of your teaser figure here.
            }
            \label{fig:teaser}
    \end{center}
        \vspace{0.5cm}
]
{\def\iand{\\[5pt]\let\and=\nand}%
 \def\nand{\ifhmode\unskip\nobreak\fi\ $\cdot$ }%
 \let\and=\nand
 \def\at{\\\let\and=\iand}%
 \footnotetext[0]{\kern-\bibindent
 \ignorespaces\csname @institute\endcsname}\vspace{5dd}}%
% TEASER IMAGE -------------------------------------------------------

%\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Insert your abstract here. Include keywords, PACS and mathematical
subject classification numbers as needed.
\keywords{First keyword \and Second keyword \and More}
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
\label{intro}
Your text comes here. Separate text sections with
\section{Section title}
\label{sec:1} 
Text with citations \cite{RefB} and \cite{RefJ}.
\subsection{Subsection title}
\label{sec:2}
as required. Don't forget to give each section
and subsection a unique label (see Sect.~\ref{sec:1}).
\paragraph{Paragraph headings} Use paragraph headings as needed.
\begin{equation}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation}

% For one-column wide figures use
\begin{figure}
% Use the relevant command to insert your figure file.
% For example, with the graphicx package use
  \includegraphics{example.eps}
% figure caption is below the figure
\caption{Please write your figure caption here}
\label{fig:1}       % Give a unique label
\end{figure}
%
% For two-column wide figures use
\begin{figure*}
% Use the relevant command to insert your figure file.
% For example, with the graphicx package use
  \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{example.eps}
% figure caption is below the figure
\caption{Please write your figure caption here}
\label{fig:2}       % Give a unique label
\end{figure*}
%
% For tables use
\begin{table}
% table caption is above the table
\caption{Please write your table caption here}
\label{tab:1}       % Give a unique label
% For LaTeX tables use
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
first & second & third  \\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
number & number & number \\
number & number & number \\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


% Non-BibTeX users please use
\begin{thebibliography}{}
%
% and use \bibitem to create references. Consult the Instructions
% for authors for reference list style.
%
\bibitem{RefJ}
% Format for Journal Reference
Author, Article title, Journal, Volume, page numbers (year)
% Format for books
\bibitem{RefB}
Author, Book title, page numbers. Publisher, place (year)
% etc
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

---

It occurred to me that a better solution would be to add a hook to the end of `\@maketitle`.  `\titlehook{...}` will place the (one column) contents at the end of the title.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}

\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}        

\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{cite}

\usepackage{times}
%\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{multirow,stackengine}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}


\newcolumntype{$}{>{\global\let\currentrowstyle\relax}}
\newcolumntype{^}{>{\currentrowstyle}}
\newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}%
    #1\ignorespaces
}

\usepackage{pifont}

\usepackage[pagebackref=true,breaklinks=true,letterpaper=true,colorlinks,bookmarks=false]{hyperref}

\usepackage{etoolbox}% edit \@maketitle
\makeatletter
\let\@titlehook=\relax
\apptocmd{\@maketitle}{\@titlehook}{}{}
\newcommand{\titlehook}[1]{\def\@titlehook{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Insert your title here}
\subtitle{Do you have a subtitle?\\ If so, write it here}

\author{First Author         \and
        Second Author %etc.
}

\institute{F. Author \at
              first address \\
              Tel.: +123-45-678910\\
              Fax: +123-45-678910\\
              \email{fauthor@example.com}           %  \\
%             \emph{Present address:} of F. Author  %  if needed
           \and
           S. Author \at
              second address
}

\date{Received: date / Accepted: date}

% TEASER IMAGE -------------------------------------------------------
\titlehook{\begin{center}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}%
        \begin{tabular}{c c c}
            \includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example.eps} &
            \includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example.eps} &
            \includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example.eps}
        \end{tabular}
    \captionof{figure}{\textbf{Caption of your teaser figure.} Please insert the caption of your teaser figure here.
            }
            \label{fig:teaser}
    \end{center}
    \vspace{0.5cm}}
    
\maketitle
    
{\def\iand{\\[5pt]\let\and=\nand}%
 \def\nand{\ifhmode\unskip\nobreak\fi\ $\cdot$ }%
 \let\and=\nand
 \def\at{\\\let\and=\iand}%
 \footnotetext[0]{\kern-\bibindent
 \ignorespaces\csname @institute\endcsname}\vspace{5dd}}%
% TEASER IMAGE -------------------------------------------------------

%\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Insert your abstract here. Include keywords, PACS and mathematical
subject classification numbers as needed.
\keywords{First keyword \and Second keyword \and More}
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
\label{intro}
Your text comes here. Separate text sections with
\section{Section title}
\label{sec:1} 
Text with citations \cite{RefB} and \cite{RefJ}.
\subsection{Subsection title}
\label{sec:2}
as required. Don't forget to give each section
and subsection a unique label (see Sect.~\ref{sec:1}).
\paragraph{Paragraph headings} Use paragraph headings as needed.
\begin{equation}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation}

% For one-column wide figures use
\begin{figure}
% Use the relevant command to insert your figure file.
% For example, with the graphicx package use
  \includegraphics{example.eps}
% figure caption is below the figure
\caption{Please write your figure caption here}
\label{fig:1}       % Give a unique label
\end{figure}
%
% For two-column wide figures use
\begin{figure*}
% Use the relevant command to insert your figure file.
% For example, with the graphicx package use
  \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{example.eps}
% figure caption is below the figure
\caption{Please write your figure caption here}
\label{fig:2}       % Give a unique label
\end{figure*}
%
% For tables use
\begin{table}
% table caption is above the table
\caption{Please write your table caption here}
\label{tab:1}       % Give a unique label
% For LaTeX tables use
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
first & second & third  \\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
number & number & number \\
number & number & number \\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


% Non-BibTeX users please use
\begin{thebibliography}{}
%
% and use \bibitem to create references. Consult the Instructions
% for authors for reference list style.
%
\bibitem{RefJ}
% Format for Journal Reference
Author, Article title, Journal, Volume, page numbers (year)
% Format for books
\bibitem{RefB}
Author, Book title, page numbers. Publisher, place (year)
% etc
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution is better suited. I solved it by creating a footnote without numbering before reading your answer.